# What is the correct term for cash?

Tags: word-choice, words, terminology

Out of the two words below which one is the correct term for "cash"?

紙幣{しへい} vs. 現金{げんきん}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[現金](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%8F%BE%E9%87%91) is the word that corresponds to *cash* as opposed to money in a bank account, etc.

[紙幣](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%B4%99%E5%B9%A3) means paper money or banknotes as opposed to [硬貨](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%A1%AC%E8%B2%A8) (coins).

Comment: What term is applicable when you pay at a store: 現金 or 紙幣 and 硬貨?

Comment: At stores, people say 現金で and クレジットカードで all the time. 紙幣で(支払う) makes sense as a Japanese sentence but that's not what people usually want to say at stores.

Comment: @user1602 If you say you pay in 紙幣 it exclusively means you pay all in notes, and 硬貨 vice versa.